# How do I get the length of file names longer than 250, then output the character count to a csv file?

Tags: csv, powershell

I've got this:

```
cmd /c dir /s /b |? {$_.length -gt 250}
```

However, I would like to export the character count and file path into two separate columns in a csv file. Adding

```
| export-csv ./250files.csv
```

does the trick for exporting the count to a column, but I also want the path to each file on the second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Export-CSV` is expecting some objects to convert to CSV. Since you are just dealing with strings you need to make the objects yourself in order to get the desired output. Calculated properties will do just that for you

```
cmd /c dir /s /b | Select @{Name="Path";Expression={$_}}, @{Name="Length";Expression={$_.Length}}
```

Should be able to pipe that into the next step easy.

Comment: Why don't you use `(Get-ChildItem -Recurse).FullName` instead of `cmd /c dir /s /b`?

Comment: @JosefZ `Get-ChildItem` throws an error without displaying the path when the maximum path length is exceeded.